# Why 0A0B0C0D is a 32-bit word/number?

Tags: binary, hex, 32-bit, number-systems

When discussing about the endian, the instructor gave us a word 0A0B0C0D in hexadecimal, and why would it be a 32-bit word?

Thanks.

Comment: I think hex is represented by two characters from 00 to FF that range in value from 0 to 255. It takes 8 bits to store that information. You have 4 sets of hex vales together, 4 * 8 = 32.

Answer (score 2):

Preamble:

What would the answer have been had your instructor given 000000000A0B0C0Dh ?
Well, the answers provided by @ergonaut and @kdbanman would yield 64-bits.

Your question:

> why would it be a 32-bit word?

The value your instructor gave does not necessarily have to be just 32-bit. It could easily be considerd 64-bit, 128-bit, or anything else starting at 28-bit for that matter.

What is important here is **the position of the most significant digit**.
To find out translate the hexadecimal value 0A0B0C0Dh into its binary equivalent 0000'**1**010'0000'1011'0000'1100'0000'1101b and note that the **1** that is most to the left occupies the 28th position. Remember bit numbering starts from the right!
Now since 28 bits clearly won't fit in a 16-bit word, we choose the next higher format which is 32-bit.

Applying this logic to the value in my preamble will also lead to a 32-bit number which is the correct answer. When classifying numbers we don't consider any leading zeroes!

Answer (score 0):

0A0B0C0D is 0000/1010/0000/1011/0000/1100/0000/1101 in binary because each hexadecimal is represented by a 4 bits.  So if you count them all, you get 32-bits in total.

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 hex digits, each hex digit is 4 bits, 8*4 = 32 bits.

Your particular word looks like this:

```
0000 1010 0000 1011 0000 1100 0000 1101
 0    A    0    B    0    C    0    D
```